# alamofire how to obtain partially downloaded data?

Tags: swift3, alamofire

I want to show partially download data. In `downloadProgress` callback I can access the Progress instance with progress in bytes or percents. But how I can access partially downloaded data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found it in Alamofire's sources:

```
// MARK: Stream
/// Sets a closure to be called periodically during the lifecycle of the request as data is read from the server.
///
/// This closure returns the bytes most recently received from the server, not including data from previous calls.
/// If this closure is set, data will only be available within this closure, and will not be saved elsewhere. It is
/// also important to note that the server data in any `Response` object will be `nil`.
///
/// - parameter closure: The code to be executed periodically during the lifecycle of the request.
///
/// - returns: The request.
@discardableResult
open func stream(closure: ((Data) -> Void)? = nil) -> Self {
    dataDelegate.dataStream = closure
    return self
}
```